# html5 javascript canvas cant draw new item without page refresh

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to learn some html5 canvas painting.

I have a html textarea where i can type in a color (eg black, red, ...) and then a button to click that fires a command to make a fillRect on a canvas.

I find that the first command works, but the second command doesn't do anything.

ie. 
input | output
red     changes canvas to red
black   /nothing changes/

some selected bits of the code:
html file

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <h1>Code Here</h1>
        <div class="code">
            <textarea id="paintcode" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your code here (will disappear after input)"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button id="submitbutton">Paint!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h1>Your Painting Here (700x700 px)</h1>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
        <!-- canvas stuff goes here -->



        <!-- canvas stuff ends here -->
    </div>
</div>

<script src="scripts/main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

main.js

```
const mainCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');
SUBMIT_BUTTON.addEventListener("click", main);
function main() {
  mainContext.clearRect(0,0,canvas_width,canvas_height);
  let input_code = PAINT_CODE.value;
  mainContext.fillStyle = input_code;
  mainContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas_width,canvas_height);
}
```

the entire project is more complicated with more complicated parsing (with additional function), but i think this is what my issue can be boiled down to. It works the first click, but the second click doesnt change the color. I know the input is still going through, and parsing properly, but I don't know why it isnt painting the 2nd time, after i change the textarea input. I need to refresh the page to get it to repaint.

Apologies if i left out some parts, but the key thing is that it works the first time.. but not the second time after i change the input and click the button again.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the button into a form? If so, can you please add the form code?

Comment: Hi Raffaele, i updated the main question! There is a text area that i can type into, the button has a listener that just gets the text info and then converts it into a string.. then javascript does the rest.

thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure? It looks your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2thya4be/1/

Comment: Hi Raffaele, 
thanks for looking into it.. Here is the github repo: https://github.com/a12b4c3/CodePainting

At this point I'm actually not sure what's relevant and what's not. Basically, there's a bunch of code for syntax parsing to create a abstract syntax tree (AST) then it executes the code for each node afterwards. I don't know what is causing the difference and am finding it quite confusing why it doesnt work. Thank you kindly for your time!

Comment: You should add in your `README.md` the description on how to run your project, as I tried to simply open the `canvas.html` file into 2 different browsers (chrome and firefox) and they both are not able to load the js file.

Comment: oh yes that will not work, unfortunately. .. cloning and executing with webstorm is how i'm running it. But i think that is too much to ask of you. Thank you for trying, none the less :)